# Is it safe to wipe boot?

Tags: boot, recovery-mode

Amon Ra recovery lets you selectively wipe  "boot".  Is that the bootloader?  If "boot" gets wiped, can your phone still boot?

Answer (score 2):

The boot partition contains the kernel. If you want to use your phone you'll need a kernel so no, wiping it means your phone won't be able to boot. But recovery will work so you flash another kernel.

Comment: Thanks Richard.  I think I've gone through several kernels now without ever wiping boot, but it's included in several of Amon Ra's "superwipe" scripts.  Do you know under what circumstances this might be necessary?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. There're several things in the Android community that are not based on facts just made up.